# What's the real point of the -f option on rm?

Tags: rm, options, coreutils

By reading the GNU coreutils man page for `rm`, one of the options is `-f`, which according to the manual,

```
-f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

Now, I made some tests and show that indeed if I use something like

```
rm -f /nonexisting/directory/
```

it won't complain.

What can someone really gain from such an option?

Plus the most common examples of "deleting directories" using `rm` is something
like

```
 rm -rf /delete/this/dir
```

The `-r` option makes sense, but `-f`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find that the man page lacks a little detail in this case. The `-f` option of `rm` actually has quite a few use cases:

- To avoid an error exit code
- To avoid being prompted
- To bypass permission checks

You are right that it's pointless to remove a non-existent file, but in scripts it's really convenient to be able to say "I don't want these files, delete them if you find them, but don't bother me if they don't exist". Some people use the `set -e` in their script so that it will stop on any error (to avoid any further damage the script can cause), and `rm -rf /home/my/garbage` is easier than `if [[ -f /home/my/garbage ]]; then rm -r /home/my/garbage; fi`.

A note about permission checks: to delete a file, you need write permission to the *parent* directory, not the file itself. So let's say somehow there is a file owned by `root` in your home directory and you don't have `sudo` access, you can still remove the file using the `-f` option. If you use Git you can see that Git doesn't leave the write permission on the object files that it creates:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 phunehehe phunehehe 62 Aug 31 15:08 testdir/.git/objects/7e/70e8a2a874283163c63d61900b8ba173e5a83c
```

So if you use `rm`, the only way to delete a Git repository without using `root` is to use `rm -rf`.

Comment: `-f` does not avoid an error exit code. If `rm` tries and fails to remove an existing file, it will return an error code.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because "To avoid an error exit code" should be written as "To avoid an error exit code in the event that there are no file operands or that file operands do no exist". As this answer is written now, it is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The `-f` option suppresses confirmation prompts when deleting a read-only file. It also suppresses errors when one or more supplied file does not exist.

The `-f` option is useful when you're aware that some of the files you're deleting may be read-only, and you don't want to be prompted about it.

The `f` option is also useful when you want to remove some files in case they exist, and don't want to care whether they exist or not. This is very commonly used in [makefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), to make a command that removes files that can be regenerated from source files. For example, if `foo.o` can be rebuilt from `foo.c`, `bar.o` can be rebuilt from `bar.c`, and `myapp` can be rebuilt from `foo.o` and `bar.o`, then the makefile target

```
clean:
        rm -f *.o myapp
```

removes `myapp`, `foo.o` and `bar.o` if they exist and doesn't complain if any of them don't exist.

Including `-f` in the instructions to remove a directory tree is not necessary in most cases. It can be justified because if you're sure you want to remove that directory tree regardless of what's in it, then you can specify `-f` to avoid getting prompted in case some files are read-only. However, people who say to run `rm -rf` are often just repeating a mystical incantation to get rid of something, regardless of whether the options `-r` and `-f` are actually necessary. If the options aren't necessary, they aren't advisable, because they increase the risk that a typo in the argument will destroy something important.

Answer (score 4):

#### The `-i` switch to `rm`

I generally see the `-f` being used with `rm` when the `rm` command is aliased so that it includes the `-i` switch for interactive. The `-f` switch counteracts the `-i`.

#### Example

Simulate the issue with `rm` being aliases to `rm -i`.

```
$ alias rm='rm -i'
```

*Make some fake data*

```
$ touch afile
```

*Now try to delete it using the aliases version of `rm`*

```
$ rm afile 
rm: remove regular empty file `afile'?
```

*Now try using `-f`*

```
$ rm -f afile 
$
```

#### Permissions

Also I believe there are instances where you have read-only access to a directory and when you attempt to delete the files and or sub-directories in said directory you'll get challenged with a similar prompt of "are you sure?". The use of `-f` gets rid of having to say yes.

Comment: By using the alias it makes some sense indeed. And your answer matches what i just show in the openbsd man pages. Although openbsd is not GNU/Linux it seems it describes what you just said. Here is the link if someone would like to check: [link]http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html[/link]

Comment: With bash you can always do `\rm` to run without aliasing ( \ being a shortcut to the `command` built it). I find the best use for `-f` is in shell scripting where you have something such as a lockfile that may or may not exist, `-f` stops the `rm: cannot remove 'file': No such file or directory` warning.

Comment: @DravSloan Yes, that also makes sense. Thank you for your answers both Drav Sloan and slm

Comment: I use `rm -f` often on `clean` target in `Makefile`s

Comment: `-i` isn't really what `-f` is about, it's more of an edge case.